# How Do I Specify Paths with Angular/.NET Core/tsconfig?

Tags: typescript, .net-core, angular5

I'm attempting to clean up my paths in my angular app that was scaffolded using `dotnet new angular`. There is a `tsconfig.json` placed in the root directory when I run this command.

Here are the relevant contents:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@models": ["ClientApp/app/models/*"]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Now, in a service I have:

`import { Person } from '@models/person.model';`

Unfortunately, I'm getting the error message: **Cannot find module @models/person.model**

What is the correct way to link paths with the tsconfig.json in .net core/angular applications?

**Update**

I found some information implying that this is related to webpack. It suggests adding:

```
const { TsConfigPathsPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');

resolve: {
  plugins: [
    new TsConfigPathsPlugin(/* { configFileName, compiler } */)
  ]
}
```

I don't see any information about what value to supply for compiler. I would think it would default to `tsc`. Plus, some examples show `configFileName` as a path, others as just the file name. Here's what I've input:

`new TsConfigPathsPlugin({ configFileName: './tsconfig.json'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the base of the angular project (assuming you used angular-cli) the `basePath` should be `src` not `.` since it lives a layer up.
The rest of your stuff should work.

Comment: I actually used dotnet cli (`dotnet new angular`) :/. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x

Comment: can you tell me what your project tree looks like?

Comment: Sure. Easiest is probably just a link to the repo. https://github.com/djbreen7/TucanTesting

Comment: the repo shows that your stuff is setup correctly, I'm not sure what else could be wrong? How are you starting up your angular app?

Comment: I use two different methods. I use `F5` in VS Code, or I run `dotnet watch run`. Both of these options are automatically configured when project is created with the `dotnet new angular` command

Comment: the project runs in what relative path?

Comment: I finally circled back to this. You were right. I needed to use `src`. However, it's been noted that this is a bug with typescript in angular apps misinterpreting the tsconfig file. I get error and red sguiggles, but it works as expected. :)